# Encrypting IV with string and decrypting it?

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography

Tonight I've pretty much gone through a crash course on basic cryptography, and I figured I don't want to send an IV through clearly, so I'm encrypting it with the string.

```
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

$encrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key1, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
$string = $iv.$encrypt;
$encrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key2, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

$return = urlencode(base64_encode($encrypt));
```

and to decrypt I've got this, but it's not working

```
$encrypted = base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['password']));
$encrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key2, $encrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);

$iv = mb_strcut($encrypted, 0, $iv_size);
$password = mb_strcut($encrypted, $iv_size);

$password = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key1, $password, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
```

Can anyone see the problem with my code and explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For a start, there's absolutely no reason to encrypt the IV. There's also many many good reasons not to invent your own cryptosystem.

Comment: Encrypting the IV actually makes it less safe. See also http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2280/why-is-the-iv-passed-in-the-clear-when-it-can-be-easily-encrypted

Comment: Don't understand what the downvote is for, are people trying to discourage people who need help from asking on SO?
@owlstead, thanks for the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to encrypt your IV, it is safe to send it in clear.  Usually it is prepended to the cyphertext.  If you analyse the structure of CBC mode, you can see that the IV only affects the first cypher block.  The "IV" for the second cypher block is the first cypher block, the "IV" for the third cypher block is the second cypher block.  Any attacker will already know every cypher block, so they will already know most of the "IV"s.

The security of CBC mode lies in the key, and only in the key.  An attacker with the cyphertext and the IV cannot recover the key, so there is no point n doing the extra work to encrypt the IV.

Comment: Thank you, this clearly explained things.
Still not sure why my code isn't working, but now I know it's completely unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to write:

```
$encrypted = base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['password']));
```

instead of what is there in wrong order for decryption.

Comment: How would the key size matter?

Comment: `mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);`  might have to be `mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);` depending on the key size